# What is best to achieve bullet ballistics: frame by frame raycasts, or CCD?

Tags: physics, projectile-physics

I plan to achieve bullet ballistics at long distances, with a slight drop.

I would also try to add networking reconciliation with a library, since I don't really have the skills or resources to implement it properly myself. I am using the Godot Engine (there is a C++ one, as a module), but I could also use plain C++, since I am seeking low poly graphics.

With CCD (continuous collision detection) rifle bullets travel fast, 800m/s at first, maybe 70% slower after some distance.

Somebody made the suggestion that it would be better to do frame-by-frame raycast instead of CCD, since raycast are cheaper.

- Bullets would pass through thin surfaces like plaster/wood/thin concrete, I don't know if CCD works if I disable collisions reactions (I want collision to be detected, but I don't want bullet to "bounce"). I don't want bullets deviating their trajectory after hitting a surface, this is too much realism and a bit too intensive (some games implemented it).
- Bullets would deal less damage after passing through a surface. Since a fast bullet can pass through a player and a surface in one frame if both are nearby, the game needs to know if the bullet passed through the surface before it reaches the player.
- With CCD, bullet drop and friction would be dictated by the physics engine, and I don't know if this works well with network reconciliation. Meanwhile, successive raycasts might be faster, and it has the advantage or letting me have finer control over the bullet trajectory, speed, etc.

There are too many unknowns about how CCD works in godot or bulletphysics, so adding passing-through AND networking would make it more complicated. I have the intuition that using raycasts is the safer way to go.

In this example, a raycast would be performed at each frame, and the raycast length would decrease at each frame, since the bullet slows down.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you've made a convincing argument for yourself why using segmented raycasts is a good starting point for your application. Have you encountered any problem in implementing this idea that you need help with?

Comment: No, I am rather asking the community if CCD is more viable considering network etc

Comment: What is it about raycasting that you worry is non-viable? The better you can isolate the problem, the better we can assess whether CCD is the right way to solve it.

Comment: It is more code, maybe I should edit the question

Comment: As far as I am concerned, I have never encountered a situation where bullets use CCD, because bullets are easily abstracted into a point, and CCD is more suitable for complex shapes.